# Python converting Django model.datetime from 24hr to AM/PM?

Tags: python, django, datetime

So I have this model field in Django that stores time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, here is how its created.

```
station_0_checked_time = models.DateTimeField(
        null = True,
        default = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0)
    )
```

The data is stored properly as verified by the admin section of my Django site.

```
Station 0 Checked Time: 
                  Date: 1970-01-01
                  Time:   22:00:10
```

However, when attempting to retrieve the data in a Django view with the following code I get the wrong output

```
print(SUBCARD.station_0_checked_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
Expected:
1970-01-01 22:00:10

Actual:
1970-01-02 06:00:10

#SUBCARD is the name of the model object
print(SUBCARD.station_0_checked_time)

Expected:
1970-01-01 22:00:10

Actual:
1970-01-02 06:00:10+00:00
```

I don't really understand the conversion that is happening here. Thank you for the help.
It is also adding 8 hours to timestamps with a 0 hour

Comment: From your model, it looks like it's storing it as a datetime object, not as a string.  You would need to use the `strftime` function to control how it outputs when you render it in your template / view, otherwise the datetime object will just use whatever it thinks should be default for the string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to manually format it when you need to see it in the correct format

##### view.py

```
from datetime import datetime

print(SUBCARD.station_0_checked_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Python strftime cheatsheet: https://strftime.org/

##### template.html

```
{{ SUBCARD.station_0_checked_time|date:'Y-m-d H:i:s' }}
```

Template Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date

---

You could also make it a Model method instead! - Probably my preferred method as it's all in one place

```py
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
  station_0_checked_time = models.DateTimeField()
  # other fields

  def get_sation_o_checked_time(self):
    from datetime import datetime
    return self.station_0_checked_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

##############################################
# Use in view.py
print(SUBCARD.get_station_0_checked_time())

# Use in template.html
{{ SUBCARD.get_station_0_checked_time }}
```

Comment: I tried both methods, with and without using it in a model method. The model method still returns the same information.

Comment: oh! I see what's going on. Do all the dates you put in that field output ~ `+1 day` off? ..seems like a timezone error, make sure your `TIME_ZONE` in the Django settings is correct.

Comment: ```TIME_ZONE``` Is set to LA time in the settings file. Times are exactly 8hrs off, subtracting a timedelta of 8 hours results in the time stored in the database. This doesnt seem like the right thing to do.

Comment: You're right, subtracting 8 hours would be a terrible thing to do. I think I got it! This **is** a timezone problem, LA is +7 hours & +1 hour for daylight savings.. So you submit 1/1/1970 PDT and the db tries to make it UTC by subtracting *currently* 8 hours, which is **impossible** as 1/1/1970 is the start!- so when you fetch it Django thinks it's in UTC and adds 8 hours. You need to change your default.. just set it to blank/null

Comment: Setting the model to blank has no effect. when saving the dt im making sure its saving as the correct timezone. printing out the time right after saving using the above methods prints out the correct time. Only when selecting all times from the DB does it convert to UTC time. I have come to the solution of converting using ```astimezone(myTZ)``` method on the desired timestamp to get the correct time. still not ideal.

Comment: I have no new ideas, but I'm jw are you setting it to a different date and it's **still** doing it? Like your doing `2022-01-01 00:00:10` and it's spitting out `2022-01-02 06:00:10`? Side note: these are truly the **worst** type of issues yo, anything with timezone and datetime objects is horrible